# Positioning elements with meta name="viewport" active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, meta-tags

In a web page I use jquery to style javascript alerts and add a virtual keyboard (which gets its position on screen with JqueryUI). Everything works just fine.

However, if I add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` in the HTML head, both popups (Jquery alert and virtual keyboard) are positioned wrong.

When adding meta viewport, should I first get the screen resolution with javascript? Or should I get the window height/width with JQuery?

If I do this, will these two popups automatically know how to position themselves, like they do when no meta viewport is added?

Thank you!